# How to disable report viewed products in magento

Tags: product, database, magento-1, reports

Our magento store is writing about 50 rows per second to the `report_viewed_product_index` table.

How can I disable this event?

I have log cleaning cron enabled but that doesn't prevent the unnecessary DB writes.

Are there any downside to disabling this?

Comment: Right, this is waiting our SSD, the main cause that SEO crawlers are accessing constantly to the site (20/30+ access for second) and as you wrote this produce an high amount of write on the DB ( and so on the disk )

Comment: A different approach would be disable this functionality only for the crawlers ...similar problem happens with the sessions, here some more infos  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119849/web-crawler-creates-a-lot-of-sessions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The event is being fired from core. You can disable this event observer in a custom module (rather then editing core files, which is evil ;) ). Put this in your `app/code/local/(VendorName)/(ModuleName)/etc/config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <reports>
                        <type>disabled</type>
                    </reports>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

The magic happens in merging your `config.xml` with the one from core that is defining this observer. Your XML overrides the core `<type>` node and sets the type to "disabled" which results in the event observer still being there, but not being fired.

> Is there any downside to this (*disabling viewed products counting*)?

I can't think of any downside in disabling this other than that you can't see product view reports anymore...

Also see the [answer by Fra](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/210406/3326) here explaining how to disable reports completely (if you don't need them at all) and other Magento code that puts a load on your database.

Comment: Very nice solution. Didn't know it.

Comment: This does not seem to be working. As with the other solution, it seems the only way I can get viewed product reports disabled is to edit the core file. Any clue as to why?

Comment: Is the custom module configured right? It is enabled in `app/etc/modules/(VendorName)_(ModuleName).xml`? You could dump the event config of "catalog_controller_product_view" event inside the `dispatchEvent()` method in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php`. And there are a hundred things more you could check...

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I had a typo. Everything appears to be working. Thank you!

Comment: @Fra, I reversed your edit. First of all, I think it is a slightly different topic. Second, if you have anything to add, please post an answer yourself.

Comment: all right,I understand ... anyway take care that the visitor log is always triggered and it is probably the main responsible for overload MYSQL

Answer (score 3):

**Don't forget: magento strongly recommended do not edit core files.**

The module which create reports is `Mage_Reports`. On one hand you can disable module, but I can't tell you what dangerous can happen. On the other hand magento create reports in `Mage_Reports_Model_Observer`. You can remove from the config unnecessary reports. Here is path to the config:

> app/code/core/Mage/Reports/etc/config.xml

The most probably the event which are you looking for is:

```
        <catalog_controller_product_view>
            <observers>
                <reports>
                    <class>reports/event_observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductView</method>
                </reports>
            </observers>
        </catalog_controller_product_view>
```

You can remove it.

Comment: Rather than editing /core/ I copied the file to /local/ and edited, but it doesn't seem to have done anything. I cleared magento cache and compiler is off.

Comment: Firstly to be sure that everything is working - try to remove all children inside <events> tag inside core file. Then you can add this fix to local folder.

Comment: Editing the core file directly appears to work, however, the local file is still not working for some reason

Comment: Most probably it didn't work because core config.xml was also merged with global config. And this part was also merged.

Answer (score 3):

**Product Page Report:**

1. Report can be disabled in the backend see *Mage::helper('reports')->isReportsEnabled();*
2. or you can override *Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer* and add your logic to the method *catalogProductView()*

**Visitor Log:**
The above report is not the only one that write on DB, the visitor log is far more active ( 2 insert for every BOT access ).
So if your concern is to limit the MySql activity you should look into the below infos:

The following methods are called on every access:

- *Mage_Log_Model_Visitor:initByRequest()*
- *Mage_Log_Model_Visitor:saveByRequest()*

Apparently Magento developers were aware by the BOT risk:

As you can see there is a filter in the constructor that check the user agent:

```
 $ignoreAgents = $this->_config->getNode('global/ignore_user_agents');
        if ($ignoreAgents) {
            $ignoreAgents = $ignoreAgents->asArray();
            if (in_array($userAgent, $ignoreAgents)) {
                $this->_skipRequestLogging = true;
            }
        }
```

Anyway it filters only certain bot ...

```
 <global>
      ...
        <ignore_user_agents>
            <google1>Googlebot/1.0 (googlebot@googlebot.com http://googlebot.com/)</google1>
            <google2>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)</google2>
            <google3>Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)</google3>
        </ignore_user_agents>
```

Comment: nicely done +1. I'll reference your answer in mine, especially about disabling reports completely.