# How to exclude myself/admin in Magentos most viewed statistics?

Tags: magento-1.9

I was wanting to find a way to exclude myself from the most view etc. in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no relation between your admin user and the viewed products.

Two ways that you can try:

1.) Create a rewrite of the report and update the query to ignore the entries from the `report_viewed_product_index` with your customer id.

2.) For future updates, you can create an observer that does not insert new entries when you view products with your frontend customer. This works only when you are logged in of course.
Something similar was done here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63304/231